# Can I disable FireWire during Mac OS X boot sequence?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-leopard, firewire

Mac OS X 10.5.8 running on 2 GHz PowerPC G5 iMac. Firewire no longer working (powers a firewire disk, but fails to mount). "About this Mac - Hardware - FireWire" displays "FireWire Bus: Warning: Unable to list FireWire devices". At boot, the Mac displays the blue screen for about 5 minutes before getting to the login screen. I suspect diagnostics are trying to communicate with the FireWire controller. Does anybody know how I could remove the FireWire startup routines from the boot sequence? Thanks.

Comment: PS. I've done a clean instal of 10.5 and updated to 10.5.8.

Comment: Does it do this even when your FireWire disk is disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting (or renaming?) `/System/Library/Extensions/IOFireWireFamily.kext`, just make sure you back it up in a safe location first. I believe this driver interacts with FireWire as implied in its name.

Comment: I'd say you're safer to `chmod 000` the kext instead of removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try booting your computer holding down `command + option + o + f` this boots into Open Firmware where you might be able to play with the boot settings